How much time chief editors usually take to make final decision on a manuscript?
I have a manuscript submitted to a good (SCIE indexed) maths journal. I received a minor revision on May 27, 2024. I submitted the revised version on June 1, 2024, addressing all the reviewers' comments. My manuscript again went under review (as shown by the online system) and when I checked on June 13, the online status was changed to “under final decision.” Since then, there is no change in online status and I haven't received a decision yet.
I wonder if this is a common practice or an isolated case.
I acknowledge that editors are very busy people, doing a voluntary service, which I honestly appreciate. However, I am confused whether I should raise a polite inquiry with the journal or wait for some more days.

As outlined in the canonical journal workflow question as well as this answer, an editorial decision taking six or more weeks is atypical. But given the time of year, perhaps those involved could be on vacation?

@Anyon This might be a possibility. However, looking at the track record of the journal, I am confident that the journal is going to publish it's July issue within two days. So, is it possible for a journal to release an issue without consent from EiC?

Unlikely that you are in the July issue. Part of the delay could even be finding a slot in a future issue that matches the length of your paper (print journals). A long paper might be reason enough for a delay.

@Buffy Perhaps, you are right. My paper is of medium length (22 pages). May be I should just wait for the decision.

"So, is it possible for a journal to release an issue without consent from EiC?" I'd assume that the EiC has given consent much earlier; the technical release itself may also take some time. I have seen many editorial decisions taking longer than six weeks by the way. People may go on holidays and have other things to do, and then a queue of submissions may build up that takes time to process.

@ChristianHennig I understand that. My only concern was what if the paper  “fell between the cracks.”
